# How can I extend My HomePage eState

Tags: dart, flutter

In my app i've the below pat of the code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int _selected = 0;

List<Widget> makeRadios() {
  List <Widget> list = new List <Widget>();

  list.add(new Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Radio(value: 0, groupValue: _selected,
          onChanged: (int value) {
            rOnChanged(value);
          }),
      new Text('Radio 0'),
    ],
  ));
  list.add(new Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Radio(value: 1, groupValue: _selected,
          onChanged: (int value) {
            rOnChanged(value);
          }),
      new Text('Radio 1'),
    ],
  ));
  return list;
};

void rOnChanged(int value){
  this.setState(() {
    _selected = value;
  });

  print("value: $value");
  this._bodyHeight = (value == 1) ? 65.0 : 0.0;
}

    // and lots more lines
  }
```

I want to split this part and move t to another `.dart` file in order to reduce the `main.dart` file, so my two files became like:

```
library myLib;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter App Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // other lines
}
```

And the other file as:

```
part of myLib;

int _selected = 0;

List<Widget> makeRadios() {
  List <Widget> list = new List <Widget>();

  list.add(new Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Radio(value: 0, groupValue: _selected,
          onChanged: (int value) {
            rOnChanged(value);
          }),
      new Text('Radio 0'),
    ],
  ));
  list.add(new Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Radio(value: 1, groupValue: _selected,
          onChanged: (int value) {
            rOnChanged(value);
          }),
      new Text('Radio 1'),
    ],
  ));
  return list;
};

void rOnChanged(int value){
  this.setState(() {
    _selected = value;
  });

  print("value: $value");
  this._bodyHeight = (value == 1) ? 65.0 : 0.0;
}
```

But it did not work, and the second file became full of errors!

What is the best way to split/scale the Flutter

Comment: in the second file did you import the material library ?

Comment: @Raouf Rahiche,  in Dart we do not import the same package more than once, correct?

Comment: you need to import it explicitly in every  file that use it

Comment: @Raouf Rahiche the 'set State' still show an error, in both cases, with 'this' or without it.

Comment: sorry i didn't notice the setState method is part of the State<T> Class and this refer to the class so you need to wrap this with a Stateful widget

Comment: @Raouf Rahiche, any idea or Sallie code how to wrap it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and reading the given answers and comments, I think the best way to achieve scalability, is to create separate file for each `Widget` that include the layout and all related function, then add it for the main file/app, for example I wrote the below code to draw a Switch, read its value and save it in the shared preferences:

file name `widget.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Switchy extends StatefulWidget{
  Switchy({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _SwitchyState();
  }

class _SwitchyState extends State<Switchy> {
  var _value = true;

  void onchange(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      _value = value;
      _savePref(value);
    });
  }

  _savePref(value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool use = prefs.getBool('use');
    await prefs.setBool('use', value);
    print('value changed from $use to $value');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      new Card(
      child: new Container(
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text("Enable/Disable the app in the background"),
            new Switch(value: _value, onChanged: (bool value) => onchange(value)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then, in the `main.dart` file I used it as:

```
import 'widgets.dart';
// ..

children: <Widget>[
  new Switchy();
//...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't separate `State<T>` from it's `StatefulWidget`.

If you want to extract that widget to it's own file, move both parts *entirely*.

So you can have

```
// lib/main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/src/myapp.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
```

and in `lib/src/myapp.dart`

```
// lib/src/myapp.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container();
  }
}
```